Testing error handling with mocha
I want to test whether my smart contract functions return the correct error messages
example function in solidity
function transform (uint256 input) public returns (uint256){
require (input>1, "the value has to be greater than 1"
}

However, when i try to test whether a value of 0 triggers the correct error message, my test fails.
expect(await contract.connect(addr1).transform(0)).to.throw("values smaller than 1 are not allowed");

The error I am receiving:
 1 passing (828ms)
  1 failing

  1) Minting of Tokens
       transform should throw the correct errors:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'values smaller than 1 are not allowed'
    at ProjectL.mintLottoSchein (contracts/tests.sol:104)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:446:41)
    at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
    at send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
    at Proxy.mintLottoSchein (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:352:16)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\test.js:42:14)

Could someone please help me out?
thx

What’s the error that you’re getting?

I added it to the original question

You need to use .to.be.revertedWith and the exact error string used in the require, like:
expect(await contract.connect(addr1).transform(0)).to.be.revertedWith("the value has to be greater than 1");

P.S., You have to install @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers dependency, if it’s not installed already.

Can you share the minimum reproducible code via GitHub, so that I can try debugging the same on my end?

It works now. In your code example, the "await" keyword is at the beginning of the line. In my code, the "await" was inside the expect() function.  I changed it accordingly and then received an error that led me to install @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers.
Now it works perfectly. thank you for your help!

Great. Thanks for pointing out. I’ve edited the answer accordingly.
